# how to apply Focus_out event to more than just selected component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, events, focus, mouseevent

I'm using code based on this [post](http://www.thanksmister.com/index.php/archive/flex-list-control-with-with-editable-itemrenderer-inputtext/).

It uses a focus_out event to detect if there is a change that needs to be committed. However I notice that a FOCUS_OUT event is only called if you click away from the textfield but inside the component.  Is there any way I can listen for clicks outside the component from within the component?

```
    addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT, onFocusOut);

    protected function onFocusOut(event:FocusEvent):void
    {
        _updatedText = text;

        if(_updatedText != _originalText){
            dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));
        }

        setEditable(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the component itself, you can do this:

```
systemManager.addEventListener( FocusEvent.KEY_FOCUS_CHANGE, focusChangeHandler );
systemManager.addEventListener( FocusEvent.MOUSE_FOCUS_CHANGE, focusChangeHandler );
```

Just be sure you clean up and remove the event listener before your component is removed from the stage (assuming it is added dynamically). That will prevent you from stacking up a bunch of event listeners.

Alternatively, if you just want to find out whenever someone clicks outside of a specific component, you can do something like this:

```
systemManager.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, system_mouseDownHandler );

private function system_mouseDownHandler( event:MouseEvent ):void {
  if( !event.target != this && !this.contains(event.target as DisplayObject) ){
    // Do Something Here
  }
}
```

Again, make sure you cleanup any event listeners if this component is added/removed dynamically.

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

If you want to cleanup the eventListeners, do something like this (called when the remove event is triggered in your component):

```
<mx:Component remove="myRemoveHandler();" />

private function myRemoveHandler():void {
  if( systemManager.hasEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN ) systemManager.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, system_mouseDownHandler );
}
```

Obviously substitute the event listeners that you ended up using (Focus or Mouse).

Comment: i added it to the init function on the list that contains the itemrenderer where the onfocusout event is and it seems to be working! now if the init function for the list is only run when the state is first visited (i think that's how it works).. do I need to worry about stacking the listeners?

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how to cleanup the event listeners in case you are using removeChild() and addChild() - please mark my answer as accepted by clicking the green check.

Comment: what i was meaning is that the event listener is on a component that's initialized only once during application runtime, so the listener shouldn't be appearing more than once.. (bc i am not using addChild/removeChild.) that hasEventListener command looks very useful though, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In LabelEditor class dispatches a **Event.CHANGE** event on focus out you can just listen for that event

Comment: you might have to play with bubbling on the dipatcher

Comment: it's calling the function on focus_out, but the function does not get called so I conclude that clicking outside of the component does not count as a focus_out therefore would not dispatch anything. you think that if i have an event listener on my main application listening to the list that contains the labeleditor for a focus out that should pick it up?

Comment: For focus out to trigger you have to change focus, Clicking on a panel or a canvas will not change focus because they can not ever have focus. You might want to rethink your approach.

Comment: Maybe on items you want focus to change add an eventlistener for the click event and call a function to do this stage.focus=stage

Comment: Agreed, you shouldn't use focusOut if you're really interested in the text currently being typed in.  Use the change event.

Comment: focus out is to commit the change to a database.. don't want to do that every character the user types.. this way i can have reset easily as well.

Comment: If you are committing data to a database it should be done legitimately and with the user knowledge. Plus the fact you will get tons of empty data sent off to your server doing it this way.